# How to assign multiple elements to single list variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm still pretty new to programming and python. Building a project to automate some tedious tasks at my day job. I have a working python script that pulls data from several websites and compares it to ensure our advertising is consistent across several advertising platforms. I'm going to explain the goal of what I'm trying to do then explain how I tried to do it and see if I'm on the right track and just not doing it properly or if there's a better route to go hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

My work has ALL of our inventory listed on our own personal website (website A) and another website (website B) has ONLY items costing $150 or more. So what I'm trying to do is scrape the name/price of ONLY the items greater than or equal to $150 on website A and then scrape all items on website B and take the list of items and subtract website B from website A and get a remainder of items on website A that are $150 or more that aren't listed on website B. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
    xtitles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-name")
    xprices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("content-item price")
    xjoined = {}

    for title in xtitles:
        xtitletext = [title.text]
    for price in ggprices:
        xpricetext = price.text
        xjoined.update({xtitletext:xpricetext})

    print(xjoined)

    driver.quit()
```

This is some sample code I tried to use. I feel like I'm close but can't quite get it to work properly. Trying to pull the title and price of the item from website A and merge them together so I can pull the same from website B and do the cross-check. There's probably a better way to do this than the way I'm doing it but figured I would ask here and see what people say. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is **driver**? Are you using BeautifulSoup for scrapping?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about [set intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)).
Let's assign some arbitrary identifiers to expensive items on the personal and the other website, and find the [difference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference):

```
site_a = set('cdeghklm')
site_b = set('cefhijlnop')
print(sorted(site_a - site_b))

['d', 'g', 'k', 'm']
```

Comment: While I think this answer is headed in the right direction, I'm guessing that it's going to be too simple for OP to expand for his own use given his newness and example. Would you update your example to show something like an array of products where a product consists of a name and price? Then show how to dump all products that exist on site A but not on site B and all products where the price on site B is not the same as site A. I think that would solve his issue.